# Cannot access oracle using sqlplus from another machine on the LAN

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have Oracle running on one machine of the LAN.
I can connect to the DB with sqlplus when I issue:

```
sqlplus myuser/mypass@localhost:1521/orcl
```

This works fine.

On another machine from the LAN, I have installed oracle instant client (basic + sdk + sqlplus).

```
sqlplus myuser/mypass@oracle_server:1521/orcl
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Sat Feb 25 09:10:41 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable

Enter user-name:
```

Oracle server is up and running and is reachable on the network but I cannot connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is a specific local address, `127.0.0.1`, which is only reachable from the same machine; another machine cannot connect directly to a service registered only against `localhost`. `oracle_server` will be resolve to (or be if you aren't using a host name) the IP address of an ethernet interface on the machine; on a LAN this is likely to start with `10.` or `192.168.` but could be something else.

Check your Oracle listener configuration is listening on the external address as well as `localhost`.

Having said that, if that was the only problem you'd probably see `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener` rather than `ORA-12543`. This sounds like there may be a firewall running on the Oracle server machine, and if so you need to configure that to permit traffic on port 1521.

Another possibility is that you're using a host name in your connect string and you just can't resolve that to an IP address. Check you can `ping oracle_server`; if that says something like `cannot resolve oracle_server` then check the name, see if you need to give a fully-qualified name (`oracle_server.example.com`), or at a push add it to your local `hosts` file. Or, use the raw IP address in the connect string instead of the host name.

Comment: oracle_server is defined as 192.168.1.25 on my LAN. Removing the firewall on the oracle server solved the thing, so we'll only allow 1521 now. Thanks a lot.