# Connecting to Oracle database from another machine on LAN

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Am a newbie to oracle, I've Oracle Database installed on my windows machine and I can connect to the database without any problem from my machine using the sqlPlus / SQL Developer. And I have a java application in my machine which needs to connect to the Database using JDBC driver. After downloading the ojdbc driver I can connect to the java application by providing the connection url as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:orcl`

Now, I want to know how can I connect to my oracle database that is installed in my machine (ip address:10.0.xx.xx) from the java application which is running in another machine (ip address:10.0.yy.yy). BTW both the machines are connected in LAN.

Do I need to change anything in listener configuration or in tnsnames.ora file?

I checked these links for reference before posting this question: 
[How to connect to an Oracle DB from another system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002285/how-to-connect-to-an-oracle-db-from-another-system)

also [Cannot access oracle using sqlplus from another machine on the LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442415/cannot-access-oracle-using-sqlplus-from-another-machine-on-the-lan)

Please Suggest me how can I do this one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC url has this form

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT:SID
```

So if you wanted to connect to an oracle server running on 10.1.2.3, on port 1521 (the default one), and on a database named 'stackoverflowdb' you'd use:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.2.3:1521:stackoverflowdb
```